# LibreOffice basic math function

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I need to power some values in librebasic macrocode.
We have func POWER(A; B) but its Syntax is "cell-formula"

But I need something like "pow" as native basic func.

I tried SQL func

```
POWER(X,Y)
Returns the value of X raised to the power of Y.
```

in code

```
rs1(i) = 1/(1+POWER(e, (x1)*(-1)))
```

But it shows mistake that subprogram isnt determined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! This "language" has operator "^"! My "cpp brain" is blew up.